# Cookies are not saved in browser even though it returns status 200

Tags: node.js, cookies, setcookie

I have created a simple website that works fine at localhost, now the cookie works fine but when i deployed it to aws ec2 vps the cookie doesn't work. the loginController function in my server folder although it returns status 200 and has data, the accessToken is not stored in cookies.

[here is the loginController function that adds cookies to the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJGMG.png)
[here is my index.js config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq9Vu.png)
[here is my handle login function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIIBc.png)[it works on postman (I don't understand why?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU0Td.png)
[the result is undefined when I get the accessToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leSND.png)

I hope someone can see my question, if you want to provide any more information please let me know. thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.